VS Code: The Svelte server crashed 5 times. Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc
Happens when saving and Prettier tries to format the code. Can anyone help me with this error? It's driving me insane.
Here's the error log:
Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
    at requireWithFriendlyError (c:\user\dev\lab\posto\app\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:59:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\user\dev\lab\posto\app\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:68:76)
    ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:12)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13672)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:171:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25) {
  [cause]: Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc'
  Require stack:
  - c:\user\dev\lab\posto\app\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js
      at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:929:27)
      at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13672)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1150:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
      at requireWithFriendlyError (c:\user\dev\lab\posto\app\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:41:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (c:\user\dev\lab\posto\app\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:68:76)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:14)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
      'c:\\user\\dev\\lab\\posto\\app\\node_modules\\rollup\\dist\\native.js'
    ]
  }
}

Node.js v18.18.2
[Error - 3:22:18 AM] The Svelte server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information.


Did you follow the instructions found in the error message?

@JoséRamírez Yes, I did. It lead nowhere... Which is why I posted here.

I don't know what happened, but this solved the issue...
I navigated through the WSL terminal to the directory, and opened it with:
code .

This prompted me to reinstall all the VS Code extensions for Windows, for Linux as well, specifically the Svelte for VS Code extension.
I don't know how, but the whole VS Code seems to have switched to a WSL version as new features suddenly appeared...
I no longer get the error and Prettier works as expected.
